# Why does importing a router for express in TypeScript not work

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to set up a simple Hello World REST service using NodeJS and typescript. I want to separate the routers into different files, but somehow it doesn't work out.

Simply put, for a GET call to `http://localhost:3000/welcome/hi` , why does **Project 1** work, but **Project 2** not? I've tried to look for tutorials but the code doesn't seem to work the way I want them to.

**Project 1**

```
import express from "express";
import { Router, Request, Response } from "express";

const app: express.Application = express();
const port: any = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const router: Router = Router();
const welcomeRouter: Router = Router();

welcomeRouter.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send({"message": "Welcome!"});
});

welcomeRouter.get("/:name", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    let { name } = req.params;

    res.send(`Hello, ${name}!`);
});

router.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send({"message":"Hello, World!"});
});

app.use("/", router);
app.use("/welcome", welcomeRouter);


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

**Project 2**

**./app.ts**

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from "express";

const router: Router = Router();

router.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send({"message": "Welcome!"});
});

router.get("/:name", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    let { name } = req.params;

    res.send(`Hello, ${name}!`);
});

export default router;
```

**./server.ts**

```
import express from "express";
import { Router, Request, Response } from "express";

import welcomeRouter from "./app";

const app: express.Application = express();
const port: any = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const router: Router = Router();

app.use("/welcome", welcomeRouter);

router.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send({"message":"Hello, World!"});
});

app.use("/", router);
app.use("/welcome", welcomeRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you "mount" or `app.use` each router matters. Also to go along with the order in which you mount them, the path matters as well. Think of them as a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)).

So for the first one you have:

1. `/welcome` -> `welcomeRouter`
2. `/` -> `router`

So when you do `GET http://localhost:3000/welcome/hi`, the `welcomeRouter` will handle the request since it is the first one in the stack that matches the path `/welcome`.

Doing just `GET http://localhost:3000/welcome` yields `{"message": "Welcome!"}`, correct? Then finally doing a `GET http://localhost:3000/welcome/hi` yields: `Hello hi`.

For the second one you have:

1. `/` -> `router` (I'm guessing this router refers to the one you defined in `app.ts`)
2. `/welcome` -> `welcomeRouter`

Within `app.ts`, where you export the `router` object, you have a route defined as `/:name`.

This will handle anything: `/*`. Meaning it will also handle `/welcome` where `welcome` becomes the `name` parameter.

So moving the `welcomeRouter` above the `router` *should* make it work like project 1.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the comments. I followed your advice and changed the order in **Project 2**, putting "/" before "/welcome", but to no avail. 

I too did change the sequence back and for *just to be sure*, and found that in both cases, in Project 2 `http://localhost:3000/welcome/hi` does not work but `http://localhost:3000/` does. *Regardless of the order of which app.use comes first*, project 2 does not work. I'm really stumped. :/